# jboss-5.1.0.GA SSL localhost/client Connection

Tags: ssl, jboss

I have a problem with Jboss SSL connection. When I try to connect to the JBOSS by using changing client's windows host file (192.168.80.115 zimbrax.com) with my browser,  I cant access. I am getting "Unable to connect" error. But when I try to connect **on the server** by using 127.0.0.1 zimbrax.com so I can access.

There is no firewall or other tool between my client and jboss server.

Below is my SSL configurations. (by the way there is no same problem with http:// but only https://)

server.xml :

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
           port="443" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="D:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\zimbrax\conf\zimbrax.com.jks"
           keystorePass="6v4xse32a096be4x" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

binding-jboss-beans.xml

```
<!-- For services like those listed above that need to know the
                 port of the HTTPS connector -->
<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
    <property name="serviceName">jboss.web:service=WebServer</property>
    <property name="bindingName">HttpsConnector</property>
    <property name="port">443</property>
    <property name="description">JBoss Web HTTPS connector socket</property>
</bean>

<xsl:variable name="portHttps" select="443"/>

<xsl:when test="(name() = 'port' and . = '443')">
  <xsl:attribute name="port"><xsl:value-of select="$portHttps" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

and this is my jboss startup :

d:
cd D:\JBoss-5.1.0.GA\bin
run.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -c zimbrax -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/zimbrax/conf/zimbrax.com.jks"

where should I check?

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying it works over http ? What url do you use for that ?

Please try https://ipaddress/ and let us know what you find.